# __construct() vs SameAsClassName() for constructor in PHP

Tags: php, constructor

Is there any advantage to using `__construct()` instead of the class's name for a constructor in PHP?

Example (`__construct`):

```
class Foo {
    function __construct(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Example (named):

```
class Foo {
    function Foo(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Having the `__construct` method (first example) is possible since PHP 5.

---

<sub>**Moderator note**: The question relates to functionality that was available in PHP 5. Since PHP 7.0, named constructors have been deprecated and removed in PHP 8.0.</sub>

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The advantage is that you don't have to rename it if you rename your class.  DRY.

Similarly, if you have a child class, you can call the parent constructor:

```
parent::__construct()
```

If further down the track you change the class the child class inherits from, you don't have to change the construct call to the parent.

It seems like a small thing, but missing changing the constructor call name to your parents' classes could create subtle (and not so subtle) bugs.

For example, if you inserted a class into your hierarchy, but forgot to change the constructor calls, you could start calling constructors of grandparents instead of parents.  This could often cause undesirable results which might be difficult to notice.

Comment: The edits to this answer are being discussed on meta: [What are the edit policy today for questions about obsolete functionality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426013/1839439)

Answer (score 20):

`__construct` was introduced in PHP5. It is the way you are supposed to do it now. I am not aware of any *advantages* per se, though.

From the PHP manual:

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class. Effectively, it means that the only case that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method named __construct() which was used for different semantics

If you're on PHP5 I would recommend using `__construct` to avoid making PHP look elsewhere.

Answer (score 17):

The reasoning in the accepted answer is wrong.

I find renaming classes to be a bad practice: things can get tangled when using [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) or complex dependence structure like PHP frameworks often do. It also break dependencies regardless of the constructor syntax. As a rule of thumb:

- if the class name conflicts, use namespaces
- if the class name sucks, use Decorator pattern or inheritance
- if the class has to be adapted to the project, use Adapter pattern

Java, C++ or C# don't use `__construct`, they use named constructor and there's no issue with them. PHP is, however, a different story:

**1. PHP 5.3.3 [removed](https://www.php.net/releases/5_3_3.php) named constructors in namespaces**

**2. PHP 7.0 [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php#migration70.deprecated.php4-constructors) all named constructors**

**3. PHP 8.0 [removed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) all named constructors**

So named constructors are no longer an option. But to answer your question:
the reason for the deprecation/removal named constructors is probably that PHP functions/methods are case insensitive, so in legacy PHP code there was this problem:

```
class Filter {
  function filter() {
    echo "this is a constructor, not a method!";
  }
}

// so you could never write
// $filter = new Filter;
// $filter->filter();
```

This is the official [PHP RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_php4_constructors) reasoning behind the removal of named constructors.

---

<sup>Funnily, PHP variables are case sensitive, there's little reasoning in PHP development, see this funny legacy official [PHP 4.0 release announcement](https://news-web.php.net/php.announce/22).</sup>

Comment: can you please rewrite paragraph #2 for clarity?  (one starting with "Renaming ...".  I am lost on why it is a bad practice to rename classes, and why there are no issues with Java, C, C++, and how it is relevant to this question.  Does it mean PHP also should use named constructor as Java, C, C++ or are there issues?  What are the issues?

Comment: @Dennis See my updated answer. It is relevant to the accepted answer, because Bazman gave wrong point about renaming the class: he didn't have the point about the namespaces in his answer by the time I provided my answer, he copied it from my answer later. Now he takes the credit, but never mind, it doesn't affect the information itself and nobody cares.

Comment: Agreed. Moreover, renaming/refactoring a class name is  IDEs job. Not to mention how ugly that name is, with 2 underscores :-( Since the name is unique in a class, they could have chosen a single `_` or a new, better "unique" sounding keyword.

Comment: @Déjàvu the double underscore is how every other magic method is already named within PHP, using a single underscore would have been abysmally confusing.

Comment: I really try to keep an open mind, but I have no clue what "Renaming classes is a bad practice" is supposed to mean. Like what, if someone named a class `AwesomeController` ten years ago you'd keep it that way by fear or renaming it? It makes not the smallest amount of sense to me. IDEs that allow for safe refactoring actions have existed for decades, if your codebase makes it unsafe to rename classes that's on you, not on the language or anything.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier In this case, I'd "rename" `AwesomeController` by Decorator or inherited class. There are usually public repos and package management that does scripted autoupdates. The packages have also dependencies and changes by hand break it. I admit it is not always the case (some projects don't have external dependencies or have Facade), so I rephrased the answer to sound more like my point of view rather than a strict general rule.

Answer (score 16):

The main advantage I see for __construct, is that you don't have to rename your constructor if you change your class name.

Answer (score 10):

The best advantage of using `__contruct()` instead of `ClassName()` is when extending classes. It is much easier to call `parent::__construct()` instead of `parent::ClassName()`, as it is reusable among classes and the parent can be changed easily.

Answer (score 10):

In your example `Foo::Foo` is sometimes called a PHP 4 or old-style constructor because it comes from the days of PHP 4:

```
class Foo {
    // PHP 4 constructor
    function Foo(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

[PHP 4 constructors will be deprecated but not removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_php4_constructors) in PHP 7. They will be no longer be considered as constructors in any situation in PHP 8. Future compatibility is definitely a big reason to not use this feature.

Answer (score 5):

In PHP 7, the option to create the constructor as a function with the same name as the class will be removed. If you still do it, you will get a `E_DEPRECATED`.

You can read more about this proposal (the proposal is accepted) here:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_php4_constructors

And a quote from there:

> **PHP 7** will emit **E_DEPRECATED** whenever a **PHP 4 constructor is defined**. When the method name matches the class name, the class is not in a namespace, and a PHP 5 constructor (__construct) is not present then an E_DEPRECATED will be emitted. **PHP 8 will stop emitting E_DEPRECATED and the methods will not be recognized as constructors.**

Also, you won't get a `E_STRICT` in PHP 7 if you define a method with the same name as the class AND a `__construct()`.

You can see this also here:

> **PHP 7** will also **stop emitting E_STRICT** when a method with the same name as the class is present as well as __construct.

So I would recommend you to use `__construct()`, since you will have less issues with this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5 the advantage would be that performance would be better.  It will look for a constructor by the name of `__construct` first and if it doesn't find that, it will look for constructors by the name of `className`.  So if it finds a constructor by the name `__construct` it does not need to search for a constructor by the name `className`.

Answer (score 2):

Forward compatibility. There's always a chance that legacy code that's left in the language for backwards compatibility's sake will be removed in a future version.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the main reason is that is the language convention.
You don't need to force a language to act like someone else.

I mean, in Objective-C you prefix the constructors with -init, for example. You can make your own constructor using your class name but why? Are ther some reason to use this schema instead of the language convention?