# Why I should use __get() and __set()-magic methods in php?

Tags: php, setter, getter

> **Possible duplicate:**
>   [When do/should I use __construct(), __get(), __set(), and __call() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250616/when-do-should-i-use-construct-get-set-and-call-in-php)

This is one area that I have not found any good answer. Can anyone explain to me why/how to use them correctly? Aren't they just a bad design decision?

Comment: Voted to close: "exact duplicate". Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250616/when-do-should-i-use-construct-get-set-and-call-in-php.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [documentation](http://is.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) explains it best. And it's called Overloading.

> `__set()` is run when writing data to inaccessible members.
>
> `__get()` is utilized for reading data from inaccessible members.

It also has some examples of using these.