# use Classname() or __construct() as constructor in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

should i use Classname() or __construct() as constructor in CodeIgniter?

both work, which should i use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_construct() vs SameAsClassName() for constructor in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217618/construct-vs-sameasclassname-for-constructor-in-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Classname()` is the old way *(i.e. PHP 4 way)*.

`__construct()` is the new *(i.e. PHP 5)* way.

You should use the second one, if your application is written with PHP 5 *-- and you should write your applications with PHP 5 in mind !*

See the [**Constructors and Destructors**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) section in the manual, which states *(quoting)* :

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5
>   cannot find a `__construct()` function
>   for a given class, it will search for
>   the old-style constructor function, by
>   the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassName()` and `__construct()` is same that is known as constructor.

`__construct()` function is most useful comparison to `className()` because when you change your `ClassName()` you have to change your constructor name but no need to change `__construct()` and also use in child class.