# PHP Passing array into class

Tags: php

I'm new ;)

I have two file php (and one problem ;) ):

index.php:

```
...    
$lang = array();
$lang['En'] = 'Enable';
$lang['Dis'] = 'Disable';
...
```

and the class.print.php

```
    ...
include_once 'index.php';
class print{
?? echo $lang['En'] ??
}
    ...
```

what is the best way to echo a value of the array $lang directly from inside the class?

thanks :)

Comment: Pas it as a parameter to the constructor or the method that will use it. Kinda PHP 102.

Comment: or use the global keyword

Comment: `print` is a keyword, you won't be able to create a class named `print`.

Comment: Don't listen to @MightyPork, NEVER use globals.

Comment: @FruityP yes, it *is* ugly, but the whole concept of globals is ugly, so what's the problem? After all, the whole PHP object model is kind of funny.

Comment: @MightyPork it is not just ugly, it destroys the concept of OO which by the way PHP isn't actually too bad at. Every language has its advantages / disadvantages. I don't think the object model is funny imo.

Comment: print is a keyword: I know. In fact, my class is not called print

Answer (score 2):

```
include_once 'index.php';

class my_class {
  function __construct(&$lang) {
    var_dump($lang);
  }
}

$my_object = new my_class($lang);
```

Comment: You should be using `__construct()` really..

Comment: no, its the same.. using `__construct` or function with class name...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217618/construct-vs-sameasclassname-for-constructor-in-php

Comment: yes, thats advantage :)

Comment: Fully read the answer to the question, you really shouldn't be using the class name for the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I have read that, now I agree with you.

Comment: the code above is not what I tring to do ... I want print directly from (into) the class... 
After
var_dump(...);
there is the possibility to porint the array ?

Comment: Of course, you can do whatever with that array in that function, or whole class, when you pas it to variable inside class.