# Assign the value to the Object in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Actually after fetching the data from the Database, i want to create a new Object and insert this object to the array but when i check the array it shows the NULL value
here is my code:

```
<?php

$query = "sql query";
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$newOrders = Array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result)) {
    $order;
    $orderId = $row['order_id']; //fetch row id
    $temp = check_id($newOrders, $orderId);

    if ($temp != null) {
        $order = $temp;
    } else {
        echo " <br>";
        $order = new Order($row['order_id'], $row['status'], $row['created_Date']);
        $newOrders[] = $order;

    }
    $item = new Item($row['status'], $row['quantity']);
    $order->AddItem($item, null);

}
function check_id($newOrders, $orderId) {
    $length = count($newOrders);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        if ($newOrders[$i]->$orderId == $orderId)
            return $newOrders[$i];
    }
    return null;
}

foreach ($newOrders as $order) {
}

?>
```

Comment: $order = new Order($row['order_id'], $row['status'], $row['created_Date']);

Comment: Sidenote, your class variables shouldn't be defined with 'var' in PHP5, they should be defined using either 'public', 'private' or 'protected'. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable in your Order class

```
var $order_Id;
```

But then you try to assign value to $orderId which does not exist

```
$this->orderId = $orderId;
```

I would suggest turning all PHP errors on while developing. You can include this in your php code to see if you get any errors. It is very hard to see all the small errors with naked eye :) Let PHP do it for you.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

More about error reporting [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: After editing:
 $this->$order_Id = $order_Id;
Still problem is same

Comment: because you are  using $this incorrectly. $this->$var means "access the field of $this with the name held in variable $var", which is empty. Correct is $this->var

Comment: Yes Adder is right. Replace it with $this->order_Id = $order_Id;

Comment: @Adder can u explain me, In the main code i got some Notices during output, notice are **Notice: Undefined property: Order::$53 in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\new_latest.php on line 46**

and the line is
_if ($newOrders[$i]->$orderId == $orderId)_

Comment: you got an extra $ in the variable name, it should read '$newOrders[$i]->orderId'. If you leave the $ there it means it tries to read the element which has an id equal to the value of $orderId, which happens to be 53

Answer (score 0):

You have several small mistakes, e.g. using "this" incorrectly, using different name for "orderId", plus a wrong name for the constructors. The constructor name should be "Order" or "__construct", same for "Item" constructor.

```
   class Order {
  /* Member variables */
  var $orderId;
  var $status;
  var $createdDate;
  var $items = array();   

  function Order($orderId, $status, $createdDate)
  {
      $this->orderId = $orderId;
      $this->status = $status;
      $this->createdDate = $createdDate;
  }   
  function AddItem($itemId,$quantity)     
  {
       $item = new Item($itemId,$quantity);
      $items[] = $item;
  }

}

$c = new Order(1, 'OK', 'today');
print_r($c);
```

Comment: Still problem remain same....
and in the manual **__constructor** is the rightway

Answer (score 0):

Now i found the Solution in the PHP we have to use **__construct()** for the creating a Constructor....
So use it **__construct** instead of class name for more info visit:
[__construct() vs SameAsClassName() for constructor in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217618/construct-vs-sameasclassname-for-constructor-in-php)

Answer (score -2):

new_order.php

```
 <?php
       class Order {
      /* Member variables */
      var $order_Id;
      var $status;
      var $createdDate;
      var $items = array();   

      function __Order($order_Id, $status, $createdDate)
      {
          $this->order_Id = $order_Id;
          $this->status = $status;
          $this->createdDate = $createdDate;
      }   
      function AddItem($itemId,$quantity)     
      {
           $item = new Item($itemId,$quantity);
          $items[] = $item;
      }

    }

    class Item {
        var $productId;
        var $productName;
        var $quantity;
        var $personalization;

        function __Item($productId, $quantity)
        {
            $this->productId = $productId;
            $this->productName = $productName;
            $this->quantity = $quantity;
            $this->personalization = $personalization;
        }
    }
    ?>
```