# Function definition same name for class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Why this code print "AA" if I give same name of my class name my function into my class.

```
class A{

     public function a() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->a(); // AA
```

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217618/construct-vs-sameasclassname-for-constructor-in-php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php

Comment: Tl;dr update your php and enable error reporting

Comment: @PeeHaa possible duplicate? Edit: closed with another.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, each of your lines call `a()`, as it's named after the Class, it's used as a constructor function, for the class `A`.

Usually you'd use the `__construct`-function, that would act as constructor, but as no function is called `__construct`, the function named after the class, will be called. So actually your output looks like:

```
$a = new A(); // A
$a->a(); // A
```

Which accumulates into outputting `AA`

> For backwards compatibility with PHP 3 and 4, if PHP cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score -1):

Constructor call automatically as soon as you declare function a()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thank you for taking the time to help answering questions! Generally when answering questions, you want to explain why a given method does not work, as well as include an alternative that helps the author in the right direction. I'd recommend reading [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).